# Equivalent for MFC's CTreeCtrl::GetFirstVisibleItem for WPF's TreeView

Tags: wpf

MFC's CTreeCtrl provides the `GetFirstVisibleItem` method which gives me the handle to the first visible item.
I requiere the same functionallity with WPF's TreeView. I need to know which is the first fully visible item.
How can this be done?

I also need to be able to specify which item should be the first visible item in the tree.
In MFC I can use:

```
CTreeCtrl::Select(hItem, TVGN_FIRSTVISIBLE);
```

How can this be accomplished with WPF?